# how to prove the correctness of recursive algorithm?

Tags: recursion, correctness, induction

```java
private static void swap(char[] str, int i, int j){
  char tmp = str[i];
  str[i] = str[j];
  str[j] = tmp;
}

public static void permute(String str){
  permute(str.toCharArray(), 0, str.length());
}

private static void permute(char[] str, int low, int high){
  if(low == high){
    System.out.println(str);
  } else {
    for(int i = low; i < high; i++){
      swap(str, low, i);
      permute(str, low+1, high);
      swap(str, low, i);
    }
  }
}
```

I implemented a recursive method for string permutation. But I got a question: How to prove the correctness of this code by using induction? I really got no idea.

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699692/proof-by-induction-of-pseudo-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to say concretely what you mean by *correctness* (i.e., the specification against which you want to check your code; see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/16630693/476803 ). Lets assume that *correctness* here means

> Every output of `permute` is a permutation of the given string.

Then we have a choice on which natural number to perform induction. For the recursive function `permute`, we have the choice between either of `low` or `high`, or some combination thereof.

When reading the implementation it becomes apparent that there is some prefix of the output string whose elements do not change. Furthermore, the length of this prefix increases during the recursion and thus the remaining suffix, whose length is `high - low`, decreases. So lets do induction on `high - low` (under the assumption that `low <= high`, which is sensible since initially we use `0` for low and the length of some string for `high`, and the recursion stops as soon as `low == high`). That is, we show

> **Fact:** Every output of `permute(str, low, high)` is a permutation of the last `high - low` chars of `str`.

- **Base Case:** Assume `high - low = 0`. Then the statement is vacuously true since it has to hold for the last `0` characters (i.e., for none).
- **Step Case:** Assume that `high - low = n + 1`. Furthermore, as *induction hypothesis* (IH) we may assume that the statement is true for `n`. From `high - low = n + 1` we have that `high - (low + 1) = n` (since `high` must be strictly larger than `low` for `high - low = n + 1` to hold). Thus, by IH, every output of `permute(str, low+1, high)` is a permutation of the last `high - (low + 1)` characters of `str`.

  Now comes the point where we actually have to prove something. Namely that by swapping, in an output generated by `permute(str, low+1, high)`, the `low`-th character of `str` with any character after `low` (up to `high`), we generate a permutation of characters between `low` and `high`. This step (which I omit here, since I just wanted to demonstrate how you could in principle use induction) concludes the proof.

Finally, by instantiating the above **Fact** with `0` for `low` and `str.length` for `high` we have that every output of the non-recursive `permute` is a permutation of `str`.

**Note:** The above proof only shows that every output *is* a permutation. However, it might also be interesting to know that in fact *all* permutations are printed.